# Python: Find Unique XML Attributes

Tags: python

I have a XML file with a structure similar to this

```
<records>
    <record something="this" name="ABC"/>
    <record something="this" name="DEF"/>
    <record name="ABC"  something="this"/>
    <record name="GHI"  something="this"/>
    <record something="this" name="ABC/>
```

What I am looking for is a Python script to bring back all unique attribute values with the attribute name of `name` i.e.

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

The script runs fine when I put the filename in myself but when it is passed through as a parameter, it falls over.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
xmldoc = minidom.parse('/root/%s.xml' % sys.argv[1])
itemlist = list(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('record'))
itemlist.sort()
for s in itemlist :
    if s.hasAttribute("name"):
        print s.attributes['name'].value
```

However it is still not bring back unique values

Comment: Do you have to use minidom?

Comment: No. As long as it works.

Comment: So basically you want a set of names?

Comment: All sorted - will give answer in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to use a set and then sort:

Using lxml:

```
x = """<records>
<record something="this" name="ABC"/>
<record something="this" name="DEF"/>
<record name="ABC"  something="this"/>
<record name="ABC"  something="this"/>
<record name="GHI"  something="this"/>
<record noname="ijk"  something="this"/>
<record noname="lmn"  something="this"/>
<record noname="xyz"  something="this"/>
</records>"""

from lxml.etree import  fromstring
tree = fromstring(x)

print(sorted({n.get("name") for n in tree.findall(".//record[@name]")}))
```

Using xml:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tree = et.fromstring(x)

print(sorted({n.get("name") for n in tree.findall(".//record[@name]")}))
```

Both give you:

```
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
```

Use parse with your own code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
xmldoc = et.parse('/root/%s.xml' % sys.argv[1])

print(sorted({n.get("name") for n in xmldoc.findall(".//record[@name]")}))
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name parse